# Need to modify script to send an email parsed from list

Tags: email, batch-file, windows-scripting

So we've got this batch file at work to check who is using Autodesk licenses and how many.

Here is the body of the script:

```
@ECHO off
echo Running license check utility, please wait...
if not exist "C:\Drawings" mkdir "C:\Drawings
pushd "\\xxx-xxxxxxxxx.com\admin\Support\Software\Autodesk\Licenses\"
lmutil.exe lmstat -s @xxx-xxxxx -a > C:\Drawings\ACDLicU.txt
popd
start /d "C:\Drawings\" ACDLicU.txt
```

I'd like to modify the script to parse out the ACDLicU.txt file to find the names of users with multiple licenses open and append our email domain on to each user name.

Additionally, it looks like the LMUtil checks all of our licensed software, so the parsing of the user only needs to occur where the same user is listed more than once in the same section.

The next step is to generate an email, add the list of user name with domain appended to the recipient list, have a message like "You're currently using multiple licenses, yada yada yada, close out, other people are trying to work, too" and then send that email through our server.

The reason for modding this script is that running it is always a prelude to a company wide email and plenty of us are sick of getting them.

It sounds simple but I have much to learn in the ways of the force.

I've got an idea of what I'd like to accomplish, but I'm unsure of how to get there.

Your assistance in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The .txt file output is below, some of it had to be redacted. The specific license in question is License #2.

For each license in question, the lines are formatted as: User Name, Computer Name (listed twice in a row for reasons beyond my knowledge), server, start time

Txt file output:

```
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2009 Acresso Software Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Flexible License Manager status on Thu 7/27/2017 12:35

[Detecting lmgrd processes...]
License server status: 27000@xxx-xxxxx
    License file(s) on xxx-xxxxx: C:\Autodesk\Network License Manager\PAE_07-10-

License server status: 27005@xxx-xxxxx
    License file(s) on xxx-xxxxx: C:\Autodesk\Network License Manager\2018 Autodesk Licenses_Update.lic:

 xxx-xxxxx: license server UP (MASTER) v11.13

Vendor daemon status (on xxx-xxxxx):

  adskflex: UP v11.13
Feature usage info:

Users of License #1:  (Total of 1 license issued;  Total of 0 licenses in use)

Users of License #2:  (Total of 72 licenses issued;  Total of 66 licenses in use)

    "License #2" v1.000, vendor: adskflex
    floating license

    Andrew.user xxx-p50s-02 xxx-p50s-02 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 12249), start Thu 7/27 9:08
    Andrew.user xxx-p50s-02 xxx-p50s-02 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 11750), start Thu 7/27 12:03
    Ariel.user xxx-xxx-p184 xxx-xxx-p184 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 9666), start Thu 7/27 12:16
    David.user xxx-xxx-p111 xxx-xxx-p111 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 5352), start Thu 7/27 11:18
    Kevin.user xxx-xxx-P18 xxx-xxx-P18 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 8733), start Thu 7/27 9:04
    Luis.user xxx-p50-02 xxx-p50-02 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 4746), start Thu 7/27 11:32
    Travis.user xxx-xxx-p168 xxx-xxx-p168 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 1135), start Thu 7/27 11:53
    Travis.user xxx-xxx-p168 xxx-xxx-p168 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 15525), start Thu 7/27 10:21
    aj.user xxx-xxx-p23 xxx-xxx-p23 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 15820), start Thu 7/27 9:05
    andrew.user xxx-xxx-p32 xxx-xxx-p32 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 3332), start Thu 7/27 8:44
    anna.user xxx-xxx-p147 xxx-xxx-p147 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 3054), start Thu 7/27 6:56
    aubrey.user xxx-xxx-p169 xxx-xxx-p169 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 5544), start Thu 7/27 11:28
    ben.user xxx-LENX1-18 xxx-LENX1-18 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 4252), start Thu 7/27 11:55
    brent.user xxx-xxx-p164 xxx-xxx-p164 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 9249), start Thu 7/27 9:58
    brett.user xxx-xxx-p185 xxx-xxx-p185 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 13353), start Thu 7/27 7:51
    brian.user xxx-p50-07 xxx-p50-07 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 555), start Thu 7/27 10:29
    charles.user xxx-xxx-p29 xxx-xxx-p29 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 14032), start Thu 7/27 8:58
    charlie.user xxx-xxx-p163 xxx-xxx-p163 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 4353), start Thu 7/27 12:13
    connor.user xxx-xxx-p29 xxx-xxx-p29 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 849), start Thu 7/27 12:34
    craig.user xxx-xxx-p186 xxx-xxx-p186 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 7555), start Thu 7/27 8:57
    dan.user xxx-xxx-p28 xxx-xxx-p28 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 2560), start Thu 7/27 11:27
    dany.user xxx-xxx-p175 xxx-xxx-p175 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 15430), start Thu 7/27 10:54
    david.user xxx-xxx-p187 xxx-xxx-p187 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 12939), start Thu 7/27 9:21
    david.user xxx-w540-03 xxx-w540-03 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 10841), start Thu 7/27 11:32
    douglas.user xxx-xxx-p172 xxx-xxx-p172 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 13638), start Thu 7/27 11:42
    dustin.user xxx-xxx-p10 xxx-xxx-p10 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 9957), start Thu 7/27 9:12
    elise.user xxx-xxx-p37 xxx-xxx-p37 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 1435), start Thu 7/27 10:38
    eric.user xxx-xxx-p110 xxx-xxx-p110 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 14461), start Thu 7/27 9:37
    eugene.user xxx-w540-02 xxx-w540-02 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 12847), start Thu 7/27 12:34
    greg.user xxx-xxx-p30 xxx-xxx-p30 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 5148), start Thu 7/27 7:00
    ian.user xxx-xxx-p04 xxx-xxx-p04 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 2241), start Thu 7/27 11:30
    jarren.user xxx-xxx-p148 xxx-xxx-p148 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 1935), start Thu 7/27 11:24
    jonny.user xxx-P50-04 xxx-P50-04 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 9050), start Thu 7/27 9:06
    josh.user xxx-xxx-p144 xxx-xxx-p144 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 649), start Thu 7/27 8:35
    julia.user xxx-xxx-p190 xxx-xxx-p190 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 10050), start Thu 7/27 12:06
    kara.user xxx-xxx-p03 xxx-xxx-p03 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 14152), start Thu 7/27 12:29
    karina.user xxx-xxx-p81 xxx-xxx-p81 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 11051), start Thu 7/27 9:35
    kasey.user xxx-xxx-p36 xxx-xxx-p36 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 3638), start Thu 7/27 10:04
    khiem.user xxx-w541-04 xxx-w541-04 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 6741), start Thu 7/27 11:49
    mandy.user xxx-xxx-p61 xxx-MONDOPAD (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 15232), start Thu 7/27 11:06
    marc.user xxx-yoga260-01 xxx-yoga260-01 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 14639), start Thu 7/27 8:51
    marcus.user xxx-xxx-p189 xxx-xxx-p189 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 11444), start Thu 7/27 9:06
    matthew.user xxx-p50-07 xxx-p50-07 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 10669), start Thu 7/27 10:00
    matthew.user xxx-xxx-p124 xxx-xxx-p124 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 3147), start Thu 7/27 8:12
    melody.user xxx-xxx-p25 xxx-xxx-p25 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 15032), start Thu 7/27 7:48
    meredith.user xxx-xxx-p161 xxx-xxx-p161 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 12548), start Thu 7/27 10:17
    mia.user xxx-xxx-p118 xxx-xxx-p118 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 1729), start Thu 7/27 10:59
    michael.user xxx-xxx-p162 xxx-xxx-p162 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 15935), start Thu 7/27 9:11
    moana.user xxx-lenx1-15 xxx-lenx1-15 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 2732), start Thu 7/27 8:25
    natalie.user xxx-xxx-p146 xxx-xxx-p146 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 5251), start Thu 7/27 8:45
    paul.user xxx-xxx-p42 xxx-xxx-p42 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 6156), start Thu 7/27 10:32
    rasitha.user xxx-xxx-p176 xxx-xxx-p176 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 3740), start Thu 7/27 11:01
    russell.user xxx-xxx-p25 xxx-xxx-p25 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 7255), start Thu 7/27 11:51
    sam.user xxx-p50s-01 xxx-p50s-01 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 14748), start Thu 7/27 11:24
    samuel.user xxx-xxx-p11 xxx-xxx-p11 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 8147), start Thu 7/27 9:06
    sara.user xxx-p50-03 xxx-p50-03 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 10245), start Thu 7/27 10:50
    sara.user xxx-xxx-p171 xxx-xxx-p171 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 8647), start Thu 7/27 11:06
    sean.user xxx-xxx-p23 xxx-xxx-p23 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 153), start Thu 7/27 11:36
    sean.user xxx-xxx-p23 xxx-xxx-p23 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 4949), start Thu 7/27 6:53
    selman.user xxx-xxx-p31 xxx-xxx-p31 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 2662), start Thu 7/27 9:09
    sergey.user xxx-w540-01 xxx-w540-01 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 9736), start Thu 7/27 12:03
    shyla.user xxx-xxx-p136 DESKTOP-G94715Q (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 6351), start Thu 7/27 11:07
    shyla.user xxx-xxx-p136 xxx-xxx-p136 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 6035), start Thu 7/27 9:32
    sunghoon.user xxx-xxx-p01 xxx-xxx-p01 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 12033), start Thu 7/27 9:34
    travis.user xxx-xxx-p195 xxx-xxx-p195 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 12360), start Thu 7/27 12:21
    will.user xxx-p50-05 xxx-p50-05 (v1.000) (xxx-xxxxx/27005 1643), start Thu 7/27 8:43
```

**UPDATED AGAIN**

Comment: Not sure how we can help without seeing an example of the text file.

Comment: Updated to include txt file contents

Comment: Doug you really should read what a [mcve] is. Because who do you think wants to wade through that amount of data?

Comment: Updated to not include the entirety of the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q45359218.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=. " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 REM "%%a" has user-name if "%%b"="user"
 REM if "%%b" is not "user" then not in a data section
 IF "%%b"=="user" (
  IF "%%a"=="!prevuser!" ECHO %%a
  SET "prevuser=%%a"
 ) ELSE (
  SET "prevuser="
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q45359218.txt` containing your data for my testing.

You could replace the input filename with your `lmutil` command line *in single quotes* to save generating a physical file.

Read each line of the file. For each line, tokenise using `.` and <kbd>Space</kbd>

The first string on the line delimited by *either* delimiter (token 1) is assigned to `%%a` and the second to `%%b`. Therefore, if we have `user` in `%%b` we have a usage-report line and the user id in `%%a`. If we don't have `user` in `%%b` then we are reading the waffle.

The object is to report two successive lines with the same username (since the data shown is sorted by username). This is done by comparing the current name in `%%a` with the previous name found in `!prevuser!`. The `setlocal uenabledelayedexpansion` invokes `delayed expansion` mode where `!var!` returns the run-time value of the variable.